# How to change slider thumb image in ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I´ve managed to set a background image to an ExtJs slider, but can´t find how to change the thumb image.

[So far this is what i´ve got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inmHb.png)

[This is what i´m trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH8W4.png)

And here is the code (css and slider):

```
   <style type="text/css">
    .slider_background .x-panel-body
    {
        background-image:url('Images/slider.jpg') !important;
    }
  </style>

 var sliderStatus = Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
   id: 'sliderStatus',
   value: 0,
   minValue: 0,
   maxValue: 100,
   renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });
```

Comment: I Included the code used to create the slider with customized background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g.

```
.x-slider-horz .x-slider-thumb:before {
    display:none;
}

.x-slider-horz .x-slider-thumb {
    border:none;
    background-image:url('https://fiddle.sencha.com/resources/images/logo.png')

}
```

Please compare [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13fi)

Comment: Thankx Alexander, it changes the thumb, but in ExtJs 4 and 5 the image it´s moved from the center, what could this be?

Comment: OK, i was using a picture larger tan the width specified, i increased it and it worked with Alexander´s solution.